# Meteor.js & SCSS/Compass

Tags: sass, meteor

Anyone doing development with meteor and SCSS. How do you get started, there are no packages for meteorite that i could find that compile .scss files into a specific folder?

Comment: Check out this sample project: https://github.com/gdumitrescu/scoreboard

Comment: @bookcasey Thanks, really helpful. Post as answer before the police close this question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried just compiling the sass/scss into css locally during development?  Meteor shouldn't complain if you have your config.rb inside of the client folder along with a sass folder and compiled css folder.  It should just automatically read the css per norm.  Running `$ compass watch` inside of this client folder where the config.rb resides is an easy way to automate this css compilation.  [Telescope](https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope) is a great sample Meteor app that uses sass in this fashion.

--Alex

Answer (score 1):

Just to get this posted as an answer (was posted as comment); bookcasey posted this sample project as well: https://github.com/gdumitrescu/scoreboard which provides some guidance on how to use sass/scss. Hope it helps.