# How can I use source code mapping for LESS or Scss in Meteor?

Tags: css, sass, meteor, less

How can I use source code mapping for LESS or SCSS in Meteor?

When Meteor compiles my SCSS into CSS, I seem to get a file that the browser uses named MyStyles.scss.css followed by a hash of some sort.

Using FireSass, I'm losing my reference.

Answer (score 0):

The hash after the URL is probably a cache-busting technique.

As for source mapping, SASS is currently in transition from an old (debug_info) to a new (sourcemap) approach in source mapping.

On the Meteor website, i haven't found any references to SASS and i don't know how it compiles SASS. FireSass currently supports the old one.

I believe you should turn your project into a Compass project and take control of SASS compilation configuration.

Also see this: [Meteor.js & SCSS/Compass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912907/meteor-js-scss-compass)